# HBase remote Java client tries to authenticate through random port

Tags: hbase

I wanna connect my local java/scala process to a remote HBase server (v 1.1.2) (in docker). I have the following code:

```
val config = HBaseConfiguration.create()
BasicConfigurator.configure()
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "192.168.99.100")
config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181")
config.set("hbase.master", "192.168.99.100:9090")
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
```

In docker, I have the following ports open: 8085, 2181, 8080, 9090, 16010

It works until this line in the logs:

```
735 [hconnection-0x471a9022-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient  - Use SIMPLE authentication for service ClientService, sasl=false
747 [hconnection-0x471a9022-shared--pool1-t1] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient  - Connecting to docker-hbase/192.168.99.100:39160
896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient  - Use SIMPLE authentication for service MasterService, sasl=false
896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient  - Connecting to docker-hbase/192.168.99.100:43454
```

My issue is that this ClientService and MasterService tries to connect on a different port (in this case 39160 and 43454) every time I restart the service, so that I cannot fix the port to be opened in docker.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start HBase in a pseudo-distributed mode. For details see my answer here [How to specify RPC server port for hbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524733/how-to-specify-rpc-server-port-for-hbase/43540376)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hconf)
```

It should be:

```
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
```